Bubbles inside Packed bubble all the same size
The packed bubble chart I am rendering, is rendering bubbles of the same size. The outer bubble is sizing correctly but the inner bubbles are all the same size. How to fix that issue?
My code:


Highcharts.chart('container',  {
  "chart": {
    "backgroundColor": "#fbfcf8",
    "type": "packedbubble",
    "height": "100%"
  },
  "accessibility": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": true,
    "buttons": {
      "contextButton": {
        "menuItems": ["viewFullscreen", "printChart", "separator", "downloadPNG", "downloadJPEG", "separator", "downloadPDF", "downloadCSV"]
      }
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "itemStyle": {
      "color": "#000"
    }
  },
  "rangeSelector": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "navigator": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "scrollbar": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "useHTML": true,
    "pointFormat": "<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}"
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "packedbubble": {
      "minSize": "1%",
      "maxSize": "50%",
      "zMin": 0,
      "zMax": 100,
      "layoutAlgorithm": {
        "gravitationalConstant": 0.05,
        "splitSeries": true,
        "seriesInteraction": false,
        "dragBetweenSeries": true,
        "parentNodeLimit": true
      },
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true,
        "format": "{point.name}",
        "style": {
          "color": "black",
          "textOutline": "none",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Africa",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Central Africa",
      "value": 229790
    }, {
      "name": "Bambara",
      "value": 62888
    }, {
      "name": "English to Africa",
      "value": 223709
    }, {
      "name": "French to Africa",
      "value": 271162
    }, {
      "name": "Horn of Africa",
      "value": 749994
    }, {
      "name": "Hausa",
      "value": 353972
    }, {
      "name": "Swahili",
      "value": 71468
    }, {
      "name": "Portuguese",
      "value": 162804
    }, {
      "name": "Zimbabwe",
      "value": 3014551
    }, {
      "name": "Somali",
      "value": 394063
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "East Asia & Pacific",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Burmese",
      "value": 5782227
    }, {
      "name": "Cantonese",
      "value": 13561
    }, {
      "name": "Indonesian",
      "value": 818406
    }, {
      "name": "Khmer",
      "value": 549068
    }, {
      "name": "Korean",
      "value": 1221
    }, {
      "name": "Lao",
      "value": 14575
    }, {
      "name": "Mandarin",
      "value": 117590
    }, {
      "name": "Thai",
      "value": 13818
    }, {
      "name": "Vietnamese",
      "value": 1562159
    }, {
      "name": "Tibetan",
      "value": 313127
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "USA",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Central News",
      "value": 778822
    }, {
      "name": "Public Affairs",
      "value": 332
    }, {
      "name": "Learning English",
      "value": 21713
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Eurasia",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Albanian",
      "value": 166437
    }, {
      "name": "Russian",
      "value": 929708
    }, {
      "name": "Serbian",
      "value": 21849
    }, {
      "name": "Ukrainian",
      "value": 607360
    }, {
      "name": "Bosnian",
      "value": 51562
    }, {
      "name": "Georgian",
      "value": 54156
    }, {
      "name": "Macedonian",
      "value": 18117
    }, {
      "name": "Armenian",
      "value": 500440
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Latin America",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Creole",
      "value": 963343
    }, {
      "name": "Spanish",
      "value": 408840
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "South & Central Asia",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "value": 5336501
    }, {
      "name": "Azerbaijani",
      "value": 186380
    }, {
      "name": "Bangla",
      "value": 338060
    }, {
      "name": "Deewa",
      "value": 8579962
    }, {
      "name": "Kurdish",
      "value": 1251110
    }, {
      "name": "Uzbek",
      "value": 53364
    }, {
      "name": "Turkish",
      "value": 164166
    }, {
      "name": "Urdu",
      "value": 3964188
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "News Network",
    "data": [{
      "name": "News",
      "value": 174176
    }]
  }]
});
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        This chart shows how packed bubble charts can be grouped by series,
        creating a hierarchy.
    </p>
</figure>



Link to my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nb_nb_nb/em9ot1ag/2/
How to size bubbles based on value?

You can increase the plotOptions > packedbubble > zMax value. Because of each value is bigger than 100, it displays all with the same size. Also, see this example and its code: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/packed-bubble-split
